# Only append NEW project to collectionview (Firebase/Firestore)

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

On an app Im working on, users are able to upload projects by selecting an "upload project" button. Selecting this button triggers a segue to a screen where the user can now input their information for the project. Once the information is filled in and users select "upload", the screen dismisses itself, returning the user to their profile. **The problem is that when a user returns to the profile screen, the project they just uploaded does not show in the collection view. it only shows the projects that were downloaded when the user first viewed their profile.**

To try and fix this, I added a **snapshot listener**. The problem with this is: It loads the new project in, but in return, it loads every project twice. **How can I set it up to where only the new project is appended, instead of every project being added again?**

```
func setUserProjects(){
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let docRef = db.collection("projects")
    
    docRef.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid!).getDocuments { (snapshot, err) in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error:\(err)")
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                var dictionary = document.data()
                let project = Project(dictionary: dictionary as [String: AnyObject])
                project.id = document.documentID
                self.userProjects.append(project)
                self.userProjects.uniqued()
            }
        }
        self.projectsCollectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    docRef.whereField("uid", isEqualTo: uid!).addSnapshotListener { snapshot, err in
        if let err = err {
            print("Error:\(err)")
        } else {
            for document in snapshot!.documents {
                var dictionary = document.data()
                let project = Project(dictionary: dictionary as [String: AnyObject])
                project.id = document.documentID

                ///only append the project if it's not already added
                if !self.userProjects.contains(project) {
                    self.userProjects.append(project)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: how about simply adding `self.userProjects.removeAll()` before the
        for loop where you have `self.userProjects.append(project)`.

Comment: If you want to avoid duplicates you can also use OrderedSet which is part of [swift collections library](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections) that apple has made. By appending to set, the duplicates are avoided.

Comment: There are a couple of options but it depends on how how you want the app to behave. One option as suggested by @workingdogsupportUkraine above, is when the user returns to the their profile, erase the dataSource and reload the documents. The second is use a listener which reads in all of the docs on first load and then notifies the app of changes thereafter. In that case you'll need to handle each type of change accordingly; `.added`, `.modified`, or `.removed`. See [View changes between snapshots](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots)